# TypeError: CraiglistScraper() takes no arguments

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

working on scraping with selenium and python and keep getting TypeError: CraiglistScraper() takes no arguments

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Aug  3 08:25:31 2019

@author: daver
"""

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

class  CraiglistScraper(object):
    def _init__(self, location, postal, max_price, radius):
        self.location = location
        self.postal = postal
        self.max_price = max_price
        self.radius = radius
        self.url = f"https://{location}, craigslist.org/search/sss?/search_distance = {radius}&postal = {postal}&max_price={max_price}"
    def test(self):
        print(self.url)
location='sfbay'
postal='9420'
max_price ="500"
radius='5'
scraper = CraiglistScraper(location, postal, max_price, radius)
scraper.test()
```

Trying to get the url.

Comment: This is just a typo. `_init__` needs to be `__init__` (note the underscores).

Comment: Never in a million years would I'd catch that. Thank You!!!

Comment: You'll get used to spotting errors like that. If it's saying that CragslistScraper takes no arguments, that means the constructor to the class doesn't take any arguments. Since you have a constructor defined though, the first thing to check is that you've defined it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Carcigenicate Found it.

_init__ needs to be `__init__` 
Two underscores in front of and two in the back.
The url is:

https://sfbay, craigslist.org/search/sss?search_distance = 5&postal = 9420&max_price=500